# Correlating number values with text values from different fields in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, correlation, values

I need to create a vector layer for representing the geology of an area. I have the geological map, a raster file.

[image]

I made some polygons and I named them in the attribute table, but I  don`t want to spend time writing the name of the rocks associated with each polygon. I made another field named code and I want to correlate those codes with the polygon names, so when I introduce that code, the name associated appears.

[image]

I think that I can do this in Field Calculator, but I don`t know how.

Is there any possibility to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a [coded domain](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/creating-new-attribute-domains-creating-a-new-code.htm).  In addition to being a more efficient way of storing the data (it manages the lookup table for you); you can also symbolize by category while editing and each of the domain categories will be available to you as a template which can help fill out the attribute table for you.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a lookup table, containing the code and description for each rock type:

[image]

Set up the fields similar to this (data type of CODE should be the same in the polygon layer too):

[image]

Then just join the data based on the CODE column:

[image]

Result should show description for each instance of that code:

[image]

If you want to make this join permanent, you could use the [Join Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm) tool once you've finished digitising.